# trying to get an element from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, xml

i have an array after convert it from xml data and i have var_dump the data in array like :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#651 (1) {
  ["authenticationSuccess"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#652 (1) {
    ["user"]=>
    string(9) "yassine"
  }
}
```

i want to get the value the attribut user that equal "yassine" in this cas . 
i trying

> ```
> $xml["authenticationSuccess"]["user"]
> ```

but not working  , it return null value , is there any solution to get this data from the array  .

some help please

Comment: Use var_dump($xml) for see your var and the type of var. I'm think it's not array but object (so get by something like `$xml->authenticationSucess->user`

Answer (score 3):

It seems your variable is not array but object, so you need to use `$xml->authenticationSuccess->user;`

Answer (score 2):

As the `var_dump` says, you have an `object` instead of an associative array. You can access object fields like this:

```
$xml->authenticationSuccess->user;
```

or this:

```
$xml->{"authenticationSuccess"}->{"user"};
```

Comment: but it still as  SimpleXMLElement Object not a string value

Comment: Does `$xml->{"authenticationSuccess"}->{"user"}` return an instance of ` SimpleXMLElement`?

Comment: SimpleXMLElement objects can be cast to a string (`$variable = (string)$element;`) and will be cast automatically if you use them in in a string context (`echo $element;`) .